# is there any way to load commerce_products into a collection in rules configuration

Tags: commerce, rules

I need to load all commerce products that their status is "active" into a collection in rules configuration.

I searched in internet and also I tried rules bonus pack but the didn't help me.

Is there any way to load commerce products into a collection and iterate collection via loop ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that VBO (Views bulk operation) give me ability to load views result into a collection in rules.

Just install VBO and make a view and use it.

Comment: Good answer. Just make sure your rules are components and you're off to the races!

Comment: can you explain it how yo do that??

Comment: Yes, At first I created a view that collects commerce products (in field you must add vbo field). then in rules, you see load view result into a list. finally I made a loop to iterate each item in list. It is working perfect.